# Google App engine datastore one to many and many to many relationships - list vs mapping

Tags: java, google-app-engine, relationships

My site on GAE allows people to create postings.  It also allows people to  edit postings and review  them.

Users should be able to retrieve a list of postings they have created, list of postings they have edited and a list of postings they have reviewed.  Also, it would be nice to be able to view all reviews for a product.

Two solutions present themselves and I was wondering as to the pros and cons of each:

Solution 1:
in user object/entity store lists containing the ids of created or edited or reviewed postings.

Solution 2:
Store a mapping.  So for every review (for example) store a new entity that contains userId and posting Id.  Retrieve all postings created by a specific user using a query.

Which would you advise?

Solution 2 seems more scalable but more costly.

Comment: Solution 1 will not work except for limited cases. There is a max list size you will reach and those list cant be searched efficiently

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565189/many-to-many-relationships-in-google-app-engine-datastore-ndb?rq=1 it's the same. be careful of the limit of the list